# How to get custom field returned by Platform Event in Lightning Aura Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, javascript, platform-event

I haven't been able to figure out how to access a Custom Field on a Platform Event within an Aura Component js callback handler, does anyone know how I can do this, or where it exists in the documentation? I haven't been able to find anything.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to include the code you've tried so far? Even if it's not correct/working, it would help us diagnose the problem with you.

Comment: I haven't tried any code because I flat out don't know how to do it, I haven't been able to find any documentation anywhere.

Comment: @nicolevy I have the details added as an answer as how you can achieve this if you subscribe to events in an aura component as in the documentation. See if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you follow the example in the [`lightning:empApi`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:empApi/documentation) documentation, then you will observe that when you are subscribed to an event, the event data is *stringified* as JSON.

```
// Subscribe to an event
empApi.subscribe(channel, replayId, $A.getCallback(eventReceived => {
    // Process event (this is called each time we receive an event)
    console.log('Received event ', JSON.stringify(eventReceived));
}))
.then(subscription => {
    ...
});
```

The above snippet prints as following, where you will observe that any Custom Fields defined on your Platform Event are present in the `payload` attribute.

```
{
  "data": {
    "schema": "xxxx",
    "payload": {
      "My_Custom_Field1__c": "value",
      "My_Custom_Field2__c": "value",
      "CreatedById": "xxx",
      "CreatedDate": "xxx"
    },
    "event": {
      "replayId": 11
    }
  },
  "channel": "/event/My_Event__e"
}
```

Once you have this JSON, you can always retrieve the custom field values defined on your Platform Event from there. Your `subscribe()` function will then look like as:

```
empApi.subscribe(channel, replayId, $A.getCallback(eventReceived => {
    // Process event (this is called each time we receive an event)
    console.log('Received event ', JSON.stringify(eventReceived));

    // parse the JSON 
    var jsonRes = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(eventReceived));

    // retrieve the custom field values now
    var myCustomField1 = jsonRes.data.payload.My_Custom_Field1__c;
}))
.then(subscription => {
    ...
});
```